# How to use this Factory class efficiently?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, factory

Consider the following `abstract` base classes and child classes.

```
public abstract class SerializableObject<T> : IByteSerializable<T>
{
    public abstract IByteSerializableFactory<T> GetFactory();
}

public abstract class SerializableObjectFactory<T> : IByteSerializableFactory<T>
{
    public abstract byte[] GetBytes(T obj);
    public abstract T GetObject(byte[] bytes);
}

public class UID : SerializableObject<UID>
{
    public string UniqueID { get; private set; }

    internal UID(string uid)
    {
        UniqueID = uid;
    }

    public override IByteSerializableFactory<UID> GetFactory()
    {
        return new UIDFactory();
    }
}

public class UIDFactory : SerializableObjectFactory<UID>
{
    public static Encoding CharacterEncoding = Encoding.ASCII;

    public UID CreateObject(string uid)
    {
        return new UID(uid);
    }

    public override byte[] GetBytes(UID obj)
    {
        return CharacterEncoding.GetBytes(obj.UniqueID);
    }

    public override UID GetObject(byte[] bytes)
    {
        try
        {
            return CreateObject(CharacterEncoding.GetString(bytes));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Is the only way to use the `GetObject(byte[] bytes)` method in such a Factory class to call it like this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] bytes = ...
    UID uid = new UIDFactory().GetObject(bytes);
}
```

Is it not inefficient to instantiate a `UIDFactory` every time I need to deserialize `byte[]` data to a `UID` object?

Is this another case where I should quit worrying and just let the CLR handle it?

Comment: Given that `CreateObject` isn’t even `override` you should probably just do `new UID("12345678")`. But unless it’s actually a performance problem, you likely don’t need to worry about creating an instance of this thing each time, no.

Comment: @Ryan The question is more to do with using the Factory class to use the `GetObject(byte[] bytes)` method and I'll update the question.  Thanks though!

Comment: Why are you using a factory? What does it add over a ctor? How often is it called? What criteria might make the factory differ? Without knowing that it's impossible to judge whether the performance impact will matter, be significant, or what to do about it.

Comment: Can the factory methods be static?

Comment: @toddmo I *think* I understand what you're getting at, but I would prefer to be able to code to an interface and stipulate the signatures of the serialize and deserialize methods, which is one reason I'm using a separate factory class with an associated interface

Comment: @JonHanna the primary reason for the factory is to separate the de/serialization of the object from the object itself, and to be able to stipulate the signatures of those methods.  There could be thousands of these objects floating around, though many may be created and taken out of scope quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UIDFactory` object uses the default constructor, so very little work is involved. Depending on how often your instantiate it, this doesn't seem to be a large problem.

Maybe keeping an instance alive throughout your `main` or using a singleton would help.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  A question that will have an answer on a sliding scale: how can I determine if using a singleton would be of benefit to the design?  This will be one of many such classes which implement interfaces through these two abstract classes.

Comment: To be honest my suggestion would be not to bother with this until late in your project and only if performance becomes an issue